Webflux and Flux<String> issue with whitespaces
I am trying to consume a REST service that produces a response of this type: ResponseEntity<Flux>.
My requirement is to perform benchmarks on the generation of individual tokens, so it's essential to work with the flux. The REST call works, but there seems to be an issue with whitespace characters.
        Flux<String> eventStream=
          webClientBuilder
                    .clientConnector(new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient))
                    .baseUrl(baseUrl)
                    .build()
                    .post()
                    .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path(uri).queryParam("temperature", "0.3").build(llmType))
                    .accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM).headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.addAll(headers))
                    .bodyValue(body)
                    .retrieve()
                    .bodyToFlux(String.class);
        
        List<String> resultList=
                            eventStream
                            .doOnNext(event->{
                                log.info(event.toString()+" "+event.length());
                            })
                            .doOnComplete(() -> {
                                log.debug("Completed thread {}..................",id);
                            })
                            .collectList()
                            .block();
        
        log.info(String.join("",resultList));

"Certo!Eccoperteunafilastroccaincantevoleevivace,pensataperincantareedivertirechilalegge...."
Expected
"Certo! Ecco per te una filastrocca incantevole e vivace,p ensata per incantare e divertire chi la legge ..."

Are you sure you are retrieving an MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM as that might not be what you think it is.

@M.Deinum the post result in curl works fine
curl -X 'POST'   'http://localhost:8070/api/v1/ai/assistant/OPENAI?n=1'   -H 'accept: text/event-stream'   -H 'X-Account-ID: myTenant:myUsername'   -H 'Content-Type: application/json'   -d '{
"messages": [
{
"role": "system",
"content": "Tell me a joke?"
}
]
}'
data:
data:Sure
data:!
data: Here
data:'s
data: a
data: light
data:-hearted
data: one
data: for
data: you
data::
data:
data:
data:Why

i can see leading whitespace are there over the wire (running with logging.level.reactor.netty.http.client=TRACE)
I think it is due to ServerSentEventHttpMessageReader::buildEvent trimming every line.

The problem is you aren't doing anything with the event(s), you are just shoehorning everything into strings.

@M.Deinum : No, he has a point. Leading spaces appear to be removed from its data values. Now, the problem is that HTML specification states about interpreting an event stream that, if a data: fields is followed by a whitespace, it MUST be ignored, and therefore that data:text results to the same value as data: text : text. And, so, if the server encodes event values asdata:<Value> without space separator, when  starts with a space... it's gone.

While that is true, depending on the payload it might not matter but as that isn't part of the question (what is actually being received) that is impossible to answer.
